# Help with popcorn cart wheels

Tags: design, vehicle

Can someone identify the wheel attachments for a [LEGO popcorn cart](https://thebrickshowshop.com/products/lego-popcorn-vending-cart?variant=31174755909735&currency=USD&gclid=CjwKCAjwwYP2BRBGEiwAkoBpAiwpG4vNXqvE2J06N_o260CDE-PIyQGz73MbPjWlc1_3x8xD7l7wbBoCWJQQAvD_BwE) [wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18978a#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) like this?

How do we connect it to the axle? Is there a good tutorial on LEGO wheels somewhere I can read?

Comment: The second one is almost entirely made of clone-brand parts that haven't existed in the LEGO universe, and those include the wheels. And that means that we can't help you with them.

Comment: @mindstormsboi No, all bricks are authentic in this, except printing and or stickers...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "wheels" are really the hubs, mostly from the various Speed Champions cars among others.

The inside of the wheel takes a standard stud, so you should be able to use:

1. Plate Modified 2x2 with Pin Hole
2. Technic Pin 1/2
3. Wheel Cover 5 Spoke

[image: Exploded wheel]

Beyond the primary question of how to build these particular wheels, there are a few common themes among wheels and axles across the system (there are clearly more than those shown here, but these cover most of the typical "official" connections you'll come across at the moment):
[image: Various wheels and axles]